# Convert US Dollar / lb to Canadian Dollar / kg

Tags: ratio

I can find exchange rate conversions and lbs to kgs. How can I convert USD/LB to CAD/KG? What is the formula? Specifically, I have $1.61 / lb and I need to know what that is in CAD/KG.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the exchange rate is $a$ CAD/USD, and you have $b$ lbs/kg, then $$Y\left[\frac{CAD}{kg}\right]=X\left[\frac{USD}{lbs}\right]a\left[\frac{CAD}{USD}\right]b\left[\frac{lbs}{kg}\right]$$

Alternatively, you can just google "USD/lbs to CAD/kg"

Comment: Give that CAD is 1.32 to 1 USD, is the following correct? [1.61/1]*[1.32/1]*[1/0.4535923] = 4.6853 CAD per KG

Comment: Yes, that's correct. See [google's conversion](https://www.google.com/search?channel=fs&q=1.61+USD%2Flbs+to+CAD%2Fkg)

Answer (score 0):

There are 0.76 Canadian dollars per U.S. dollar (I had to look that up) and 2.2 pounds per kg. (I was pretty sure of that but looked it up anyway).

So one Us Dollar/pound= (one US Dollar/pound)* (2.2 pound/kg)(0.75 Canadian Dollars/US Dollar)= (2.2)(0.75) Canadian Dollars/kg= 1.65 Canadian Dollars per kilogram.

Comment: Your exchange rate is wrong. It is the other way around, 0.75 USD for 1 CAD. :)

Comment: But I'm not going from 1 CAD to USD or KG to LB. I'm going from 1.61 USD to CAD.and LB to KG. 1 USD = 1.32 CAD. and 1 LB is 0.4535923 KG.

Answer (score 0):

The money change rate is not something fixed so you need to check it on Google or elsewhere. For the formula lbs <-> kg you have:

1 pound = 0.4535924 kilograms

That means 1 dollar / lb = 1 dollar / 0.4535924 kg

if 1 US dollar = R CA dollar then

X USD / lb =  X*R/0.4535924 CAD

Comment: So R is the CAD? Today that would be 1.32.

Comment: If that's the case then 1.61/lb = 1.61*1.32/0.4535924, which is 4.6853 CAD/KG, right?

Comment: @TomHolt that's right